# Center View to Mouse and change the position of the mouse cursor?

Tags: python, automation, blender

Is it possible to change the position of the mouse cursor (not 3d cursor) from the script level?
I would like the mouse cursor to move to the center of the active viewport after using operator:

```
import bpy

view3d.view_center_pick
```

Thank You for for any information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using context:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

For in depth help see the answers present here:

[How to set cursor location, pivot_point in script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5359/how-to-set-cursor-location-pivot-point-in-script)

Comment: In the question I meant the mouse cursor - not 3d cursor.

Comment: Just to be sure did you meant this ? have a look https://devtalk.blender.org/t/center-mouse-position-on-3d-view/9097

Comment: This is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Anything in that forum helped you in any way ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there was a surprising problem with the "bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_pick ()" operator not working when I want to call it as an external script with the "Pie Menu Editor" addon,
My programming knowledge is too poor so I'll have to give up.